# cx_FreezeでビルドしたPythonスクリプトexecでは動作するのに.appでは機能しない。

Tags: python, python3, cx-freeze

pythonスクリプトをcx_Freezeを使ってappしたのですが、起動したアプリの画像をDLしてthumbnailフォルダに保存する機能が上手く動作しません。最初はInfo.pilstによってカレントディレクトリのパスが変更した事によってプログラムが動作しないと思い。
本来のパス `web/images/thumbnail/{videoID}.jpg` を `MacOS/web/images/thumbnail/{videoID}.jpg`変更してビルドし直したのですが、上手くいかなかったのでパスが原因ではなさそうです。

そしてターミナルから直接 app(バイナリ)のある階層までいて `./app`で実行するとちゃんと動作するためビルド時にライブラリ等が上手く読み込めなかった可能性は低くなぜ直接ターミナルから実行すると動作するのにsample.appをダブルクリックで実行した場合は上手く動作しないのかわかりません。

助けて頂けないでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

**パッケージの構成**

```
   sample.app
     └── Contents
         ├── Info.plist #おそらくapp化によってカレントディレクトリがここに変更された。
         └── MacOS
             ├── app #元々のスクリプトはここをカレントディレクトリに実行される事を元にパスを設定してる。
             ├── web
                 ├── images
                     ├── thumbnail
```

**追記**
おそらく原因はsample.appをクリックしてプログラムを実行する際のパスが `/Users/UserName`になる事が原因だと思われます。
絶対パスで指定する方法があると思うのですが、それだとsample.appの場所を移動するたびにパスの変更が必要なので現実的ではありません。できればパスをapp(EXEC）からスタートするようにしたいのですが、どのようにコードを書いて良いか分かりません。

**追記2**
パスが原因だと考えていたのですが、試しにパスを指定せずに現在のパスに画像を保存するようにしたのですが、それでも上手く動作しなかったので、別の原因あるように思います。`sample.app`のダブルクリックでは動作が上手く行かないが、`app（EXECファイル)`ダブルクリックではしっかり動作します。`sample.app`はただのフォルダでクリックする事で中にある`app(EXECファイル)`を実行しているだけだと思うのですが、なぜ`sample.app`からだと上手く動作しないのか全く分かりません。

**追記3**
app化したアプリで新しくファイルを生成したりするコードが走るとエラーになるみたいです。ログをテキストに出力するコードを追加したのですが、それが上手く動作しなかったのと、試しに `open()`でダミーファイルを生成するコードを追加したり、コメントアウトするとそれに合わせてプログラムが動作しなかったりしたりを繰り返したためそう考えられます。
権限が原因でしょうか？

Comment: この記事 [How to know the current file path after being frozen into an executable using cx_Freeze?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56733085/9014308) やその回答が示しているドキュメントのここ [Using data files](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files) とかが参考になるのでは？

Comment: ファイル等は上記のドキュメントを参考にsetup.pyを記述して実際に読み込まれているので問題ないかと思います。
そしてパスが原因だと考えていたのですが、パスというより`.app`した事が原因な気がします。理由は`.app`のパッケージ内にあるapp(exec)を直接実行する際はちゃんと動作します。

Comment: 「思う」とかで推測しているだけではなく、情報を採取・ログ出力する等して実際の違いを調べてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: Exec形式はターミナルで実行してログの出力等が出来るのですが、app形式での実行の場合ログ等を出力出来なくて現在の状態では、思うしか言えなくて申し訳ないです。

Comment: .app等をデバックするツール等あるのでしょうか？

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるかも。[How can I log from Python to syslog with either SysLogHandler or syslog on Mac OS X *and* Debian (7)](https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/1890058.html), [Python logging working on Windows but not Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36046004/9014308)

Comment: 記事の提供ありがとうございます。コンソールに表示されないならtxtで出力すれば良いと思いロガー関数を作成してみたのですが、どうやらパッケージから実行する時はファイルを生成する事が出来ずそれがエラーの原因だったと思われます。（結局ログがテキストに出力されないので断定出来ない。）そして試しに`open()`でダミーのファイルを生成する処理をプログラムの一番最初に行うようにしたらアプリが起動しなくなり、処理をコメントアウトすると問題なく起動するようになったので可能性は高いと思います。